# Помогите составить программу

Tags: c#

Вычисления значения функции 7x*x-3x+6 при любом значении x; На C# приложение Windows Forms

Comment: Добро пожаловать! На Stack Overflow задания не выполняют, здесь отвечают на вопросы. Попробуйте выполнить задание сами, если по ходу выполнения возникнут проблемы, то Вы сможете задать более конкретный вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

Функция будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
public double F(double x) 
{
    return 7 * x * x - 3 * x + 6;
)
```

А создать WinForms проект и добавить необходимые компоненты придется самому.